# Is there an UML element type for source folders?

Tags: uml

I've learned *packages* are actually for namespaces. But in the model tree, I actually wanted to group my classes and visualize by the project's directory structure (like the source and header files are located in the filesystem).

Now I have a clash between packages representing source folders and it's interpretation of the diagram as namespaces. E.g. a package "include" and "src" lead to such namespaces which is wrong.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

A `NameSpace` is actually a `NamedElement` that aggregates `PackageImport`s which have a single `Package`. See fig. 7.5 on p. 27 of UML 2.5.

I don't use too many different UML tools, so I can currently only speak for Enterprise Architect. Here a package can be marked as a namespace root. And probably other tools will do that similarly. So, if you are using packages as namespace you have a hard time to also use them for a different folder structure. If you need to represent that, the only thing you can do is to create a separate package structure (eventually stereotyping them with `<<folder>>` or the like). Then you can use the nesting operator to include the files as needed.

Something like this:
[image]

Comment: Do you mean with "separate package structure" a parallel package tree, one for namespaces and one for folders, do I understand you correctly?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You have one package structure where you have your namespace. Then if you want to model a directory structure you need a different set of packages (the stereotyped ones).

Comment: Hmm, that makes me a bit sad, since I actually don't want to double the tree (since it's quite big), but also wanted to illustrate dependencies between folders (namely svn externals) by using UML diagrams. I'm afraid I've come at a point where EA with its UML is too far from keeping it closely to the real programming world. Anyway thanks for your good answer.

Comment: I think EA should not automatically see a package as namespace. The user should have control which package is a namespace and which package is just another container for grouping things (like folder).

Comment: EA offers the namespace as option (context Code Eng./Set Namespace Root). The default is "no namespace".

Comment: What you're after is showing a deployment. And if that's different to your namespace you need a different structure.

Comment: EA offers an "Artifact" element in deployment diagrams. They also can be put together as tree in the model. Is that the key element for modelling folders of my source code files tree?

Comment: ...or maybe "Nodes"? The definition is quite flaky

Comment: Well, I'd just use it as above. A package is the UML element which resembles most a folder in the file system.

Comment: I think you’re trying to model two different things, a physical and a logical hierarchy.

Comment: Namespaces are logical, they don’t have to be tied to physical representation. Folder structures are physical. The two could interleave, but UML packages are more akin to Namespaces (I.e. logical) than to say Java packages or folder structures.

Comment: Please open a new question for that.

Comment: ...In the end, what I need is something like an option "exclude from EA's namespace hierarchy" for packages to prevent "include" or "src" to be an UML namespace... but I don't think it's possible with EA. Unfortunately, this confuses every software developer here because we actually want to define the namespaces in UML accordingly as in our C++ source code...

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it now. It is a mix of packages and deployment nodes (for folders) and artifacts (for files). I use packages where classes are, to be able to sync the model back by reverse-engineering. All other stuff which is just for structuring the files are deployment elements. I hope this is the right solution, please feel free to comment this answer.

The diagram can exactly show the relationships of the classes (it still needs some explanation text), and you can see how it is located also.

[image]